# How to concatenate list objects into a string and separate the last 2 objects with "and"

Tags: python, string

I have the following list of words:

```
s = [
  "aaa",
  "bbb",
  "ccc"
]
```

The length of `s` can be equal to any number (1, 2, 3, etc).

I need to generate a single string by concatenating these words. The last 2 words should be concatenated with `and`, e.g.:

```
aaa, bbb and ccc
```

If the list consisted of 2 words only, then the result would be `aaa and bbb`.

I know how to concatenate the elements of a list:

```
", ".join(s)
```

However, I'm struggling with adding `and` between the last two words.

Comment: Do you know how to slice a list to get all elements except the last one? Do you know how to get the last element of a list alone?

Comment: what do you want to happen if `len(s) == 1`, e.g. `s = ["aaa"]`?

Comment: @mkrieger1: Ok, good idea. Thanks.

Comment: @sacuL: The output should be just `aaa`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
x = (", ".join(s[:-1]) + " and " + s[-1]) if len(s) > 1 else "".join(s)
```

Some tests:

```
tests = [["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"], ["aaa", "bbb"], ["aaa"], []]

for s in tests:
    x = (", ".join(s[:-1]) + " and " + s[-1]) if len(s) > 1 else "".join(s)
    print(x)
```

Prints:

```
aaa, bbb and ccc
aaa and bbb
aaa
```

Answer (score 1):

You can act according to last item's length:

```py
def and_together(s):
    # if one element return that element directly
    if len(s) == 1:
        return s[0]

    # join with ", "
    out = ", ".join(s)

    # get last ones' length and find last comma's index
    last_ones_length = len(s[-1])
    last_comma_index = -2 - last_ones_length

    # take the part till last comma and add "and" and lastly the last string
    out = out[:last_comma_index] + " and " + s[-1]

    return out
```

using:

```py
>>> and_together(["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"])
'aaa, bbb and ccc'
>>> and_together(["aaa", "bbb"])
'aaa and bbb'
>>> and_together(["aaa"])
'aaa'
```